# Is this the right way to add 2 arrays into SimpleAdapter?

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter, simpleadapter

I use SimpleAdapter to display 2 strings, one on the left and the other on the right, into a ListView,

The strings are in 2 different arrays. and 1st from array A with 1st in array B are in the 1st line, and so on..

Here is a part of the code I use:

```
    String[] array= getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Names_List);
    
    int lengthtmp= array.length;
    for(int i=0;i<lengthtmp;i++)
    {
        counter++;
        AddToList(array[i]);            
    }

    adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this,list,R.layout.start_row,new String[] {"number","suraname"},new int[] {R.id.Start_Numbering,R.id.Start_Name});

      
   private void AddToList(String name) {
    HashMap<String,String> temp = new HashMap<String,String>();

    
    temp.put("number", Integer.toString(SortingPictures[counter-1]));

    temp.put("suraname", name);
    list.add(temp);

}
```

I'm sure there is a better way to make what I want. What's the correct way?

Comment: Create a new Adapter. extend BaseAdapter and create a constructor that takes your two arrays, using one for each side of your lsitview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it is not a proper way to implementing this here i am given a link for you read id and get idea for implementing it.

http://www.heikkitoivonen.net/blog/2009/02/15/multicolumn-listview-in-android/

Answer (score 0):

You can use System.arraycopy to copy the contents of
**To add two array**

```
int[] a = {1, 2};  
         int[] b = {3, 4};  

         int[] ab = new int[a.length + b.length];  

         System.arraycopy(a, 0, ab, 0, a.length);  
         System.arraycopy(b, 0, ab, a.length, b.length);
```

**Two add muliple arrays**

```
public static String[] join(String [] ... parms) {
    // calculate size of target array
    int size = 0;
    for (String[] array : parms) {
      size += array.length;
    }

    String[] result = new String[size];

    int j = 0;
    for (String[] array : parms) {
      for (String s : array) {
        result[j++] = s;
      }
    }
    return result;
  }


  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String a[] = { "1", "2", "3" };
    String b[] = { "4", "5", "6" };
    String c[] = { "7", "8", "9" };

    String[] big = (String [])join(a,b,c);

    System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(big));
    /*
     * output : 
     *    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
     */
  }
```

Comment: This answer is not related to my question, my question is about adding 2 arrays into a hashmap..